# Handling Failed Network Requests with a ListView's Empty View

Tags: java, android, listview, android-annotations

I have a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) that retrieves data from the net. I have an empty View, empty.xml (using [ListView.setEmptyView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29)), for when the ListView contains no items. However, I want to set another empty view for when the network request fails (error.xml, lets call it the error View). If the network request fails and the error View is shown, I want the user to be able to click the retry button and have ProfileFragment.getProfile() be called again, as well as setting the ListViews empty View back to the default empty View (empty.xml)

How can I achieve this?

I've attempted using two ViewStubs (one for empty.xml and one for error.xml), but that did not work as expected, as the earlier ViewStub was above the other one, and I couldn't switch them back (maybe I'm using them wrong :/)

## Code:

### ProfileFragment.java

Annotated with AndroidAnnotations. The showErrorView() is the functionality I am looking for, bearing in mind that if a user hits retry and the profile does load, this error view (error.xml) needs to be replaced with the standard empty view (empty.xml)

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_profile)
public class ProfileFragment {

private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

@RestService
ProfileRest rest;

@Bean
ProfileAdapter adapter;

/**
 * The object this fragment will display
 */
private Profile profile;

@AfterInject
void afterInject() {

    // Add the API key to each request using the APIKeyInterceptor
    rest.setRestTemplate(Util.addAPIKey(keyInterceptor, rest.getRestTemplate()));

    // Retrieve and display the user's profile
    getProfile();
}

/**
 * - Bind an emptyView to this objects ListView
 * - Set the Adapter that handles the ListView
 * - Adds a click listener to handle clicks to each row in the list
 */
@AfterViews
void bindListView() {
    // here emptyView corresponds to empty.xml
    listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);   // Show the user the emptyView if the adapter is empty
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);       // bind adapter to listView to handle list items
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(clickListener); // Handle row clicks (show more info)
}

/**
 * Downloads the user's profile
 */
@Background
void getProfile() {

    showLoading();      // give the user a visual while we are reloading

    if ( !setProfileFromCache() && !setProfileFromNet() ) {
        // How do we show the error.xml in place of empty.xml?
        showErrorView();            
    }


    // Stop loading animation
    hideLoading();

}


/**
 * Attempts to set this Fragments profile via the cache
 * @return true if we are able to set the profile, false otherwise
 */
boolean setProfileFromCache()  {

    try {
        Medications cached = (Medications) cache.load(Medications.class);

        if (bandID.equals(cached.getUser())) {

            // Update UI with cached profile
            update(cached);

            Log.d(TAG, "profile retrieved from cache");

            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorHandler.handle(e);
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Attempts to set this Fragments profile via the REST API
 * @return true if we are able to set the profile, false otherwise
 */
boolean setProfileFromNet()  {

    try {

        // Hit the web and download the profile
        Medications response = rest.get(bandID);
        Log.d(TAG, "profile downloaded from the net");

        // Cache response
        cache(response);

        // Update UI with response
        update(response);

        return true;

    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {

        errorHandler.handle(e);     // Handle error

    } catch (Exception e) {

        errorHandler.handle(e);     // Handle error

    }

    return false;
}

@UiThread
void update(Profile profile) {

    this.profile = profile;

    // Update adapter to deal with new data
    adapter.update(profile);
}
}
```

### fragment_profile.xml

Used by ProfileFragment to display a Profile in my application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### error.xml

Should be shown when a network request fails. The retry button should call ProfileFragment.getProfile()

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffebebeb">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/error_title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:text="@string/error"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:textColor="@color/grey"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/frown"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/error_title"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:src="@drawable/frown"
android:contentDescription="@string/error_result" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/error_text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/frown"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:text="@string/error_result"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
android:textColor="@color/grey"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/retry"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/error_text"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:text="@string/retry" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### empty.xml

The empty view to show when a user has no profile items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffebebeb">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/empty_logo"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/shield_logo_empty"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:contentDescription="@string/empty_result" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/error_text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/empty_result"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
android:textColor="@color/grey"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_below="@+id/empty_logo"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Personally I manually hide & show proper view elements. I don't know any embedded way.

Comment: @Malachiasz While I was trying to have each XML file map to a certain screen, I may just have to put my error.xml Views in the fragment_profile.xml and play with the visibility of the ListView and error Views